# How to convert a PPTX file to PDF using Python without depending on Windows (For Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pdf, powerpoint, python-pptx

as the title suggests, I'm looking to convert a powerpoint file (pptx) to PDF using python on linux.
I have found and tested several solutions but most of them depend on Windows (pptxtoPDF, ComTypes, Pythoncom, PPT2PDF) or are paid like (Aspose.slides, Spire.Presentation, CloudMersive).
I'd really like to find a package that can do this conversion without being paid for, without depending on Windows and without relying on Microsoft PowerPoint or other third-party applications and services.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is Google Docs a solution here? Also check out [the python pptx library](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/presentations.html)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I use python-pptx to create my presentations but unfortunately it doesn't allow me to convert a pptx file to PDF. I'm going to check out Google Docs, thanks.

Comment: How about Open Office or Libre Office? Or is the point that you don't want to use a GUI?

Comment: @MartinPacker Yes I don't want to depend on a GUI or anything paid. Something like python-pptx, It runs on any Python capable platform, including macOS and Linux, and does not require the PowerPoint application to be installed or licensed. But it doesn't offer conversion to PDF.

Comment: Right. python-pptx could extract the information but wouldn't format it right.